# grep how to match some letters OR end of line

Tags: regex, grep, newline

I have some files with lines like this:

```
vi
vi-sw600dp
ddnki
xhdpi
```

I want to use grep to match only lines where are two letters at start of line and after that letters are dash OR nothing(new line).

So output will be like this:

```
vi
vi-sw600dp
```

I try something like this:

```
grep '^[A-Za-z]\{2\}[-\n]'
```

I expect, it match lines with two starting letters a-z,A-Z and then with dash or new line. But it doesn't work. \n was not assumed new line but characters so it otuput this:

```
vi
vi-sw600dp
ddnki
```

Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Consider adding what DOES happen and what you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close. You need to use the end-of-line anchor `$` instead of `\n`. `$` cannot be part of a character group, so you should use an atom grouping instead:

```
 grep '^[A-Za-z]\{2\}\(-\|$\)'
```

Or with `-E`:

```
grep -E '^[A-Za-z]{2}(-|$)'
```